# Problema con URL de función AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo un problema al ejecutar una función `AJAX` para llenar un `SELECT` dependiente, resulta que estoy trabajando con `PHP MVC` y rutas amigables, entonces al momento de definir la `URL` de mi `AJAX` y seleccionar mi primer `SELECT`, obtengo los datos en otra vista y no se me llena el segundo `SELECT` de la primera vista... ¿Qué puedo realizar en este caso para mantener la vista y llenar el `SELECT` con la información que me devuelve el `action` de mi Controlador? llevo tiempo con esta traba y agradecería un montón su ayuda.

Adjunto mi código:

`AJAX`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#idRegion').change(function(){
            $('#idRegion option:selected').each(function(){
                id_region = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'obtenerProvincias',
                    data: {id_region: id_region},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#idProvincia').html(data.html);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr,err){
                        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

`HTML`

```
<?php $regiones = Utils::showRegiones(); ?>
    <select class="input" name="idRegion" id="idRegion">
        <option value="0">Seleccionar Región</option>
        <?php while($reg = $regiones->fetchObject()): ?>
            <option value="<?=$reg->tb_idRegion?>" <?=isset($sit) && is_object($sit) && $reg->tb_idRegion == $sit->tb_idRegion ? 'selected' : ''?>>
                <?=$reg->nombre?>
            </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <!-----AQUI VAN LOS SELECT ANIDADOS DE PROVINCIA Y COMUNA-------->
    <select class="input" name="idProvincia" id="idProvincia">

    </select>
```

`PHP`

```
public function obtenerProvincias(){

    $id_region = $_POST['id_region'];

    $provincia = new Provincia();
    $provincia->setIdRegion($id_region);
    $provincias = $provincia->getAllByRegion();

    $html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Provincia</option>";

    while($pro = $provincias->fetchObject()){
        $html .= "<option value='".$pro->tb_idProvincia."'>".$pro->nombre."</option>";
    }

    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo para empezar nunca enviar cadenas html para un webservice lo mejor es que mandes el resultado de tu *SELECT* que seria el listado de tus provincias en **json** ya que de esta forma sera menos pesada la descarga y el proceso de la información, una ves el ajax reciba el json insertarlo al *SELECT* de la siguiente forma:

```
        var select = $('#idProvincia');
        if(select.prop) {
          var options = select.prop('options');
        }else{
          var options = select.attr('options');
        }
        $('option', select).remove();
        options[options.length] = new Option("Seleccionar","0");
        if(data){
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options[options.length] = new Option(data[i]['nombre'],data[i]['tb_idProvincia']);
          }
        }
```

En tu archivo PHP cambia que te devuelva un **json** quedaria algo así:

```
public function obtenerProvincias(){

    $id_region = $_POST['id_region'];

    $provincia = new Provincia();
    $provincia->setIdRegion($id_region);
    $provincias = $provincia->getAllByRegion();

    $return = $provincia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

También revisa la ruta y el webservice antes para no retrabajar, para esto yo utilizo [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) y la verdad es que me ayuda bastante ya que reviso todas las variantes manualmente de mi webservice para corroborar que funciona correctamente y no es este el del problema.

Espero te ayude esta información en algo, saludos.

**[EDITADO]**

Te agrego como quedaria tu funcion en JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#idRegion').change(function(){
    $('#idRegion option:selected').each(function(){
      id_region = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/proyecto/obtenerProvincias', // Prueba con la URL completa para descartar que este sea el problema.
        data: {id_region: id_region},
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
          var select = $('#idProvincia');
          if(select.prop) {
            var options = select.prop('options');
          }else{
            var options = select.attr('options');
          }
          $('option', select).remove();
          options[options.length] = new Option("Seleccionar","0");
          if(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              options[options.length] = new Option(data[i]['nombre'],data[i]['tb_idProvincia']);
            }
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr,err){
          alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText:  "+xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: gracias por tu comentario Cuadra2, probé tu código y sigo sin visualizar la información dentro del SELECT, sino que en otra vista al igual como en un principio... Sigo creyendo que mi problema radica en la URL de mi función debido a que trabajo con .htaccess, entonces al seleccionar el primer SELECT, la informacion me la muestra en una vista donde mi ACTION es obtenerProvincias. A demás, en tu código JS la variable "result" no esta definida y no entiendo donde declararla

Comment: @FelipeMartínezDelgado Disculpa mi error, la variable result seria la variable de data en tu caso (disculpa la confusión, acabo de corregir el codigo), el código de JS va dentro de la función success del ajax. Respecto la URL intenta poner la ruta completa en el ajax para validar que se consulta correctamente, de no ser así puede que este mal configurado tu .htaccess. También te recomiendo realizar estas pruebas con Postman ya que te facilitara testear tus webservices.

Comment: Implementé tu código, verifique que la URL estuviera correcta y si lo esta, pero ahora el AJAX no pasa por el success y me lanza al error... igualmente me muestra los datos en el index que es donde cargo todos mis controladores con sus acciones. De verdad ya no se que hacer, he intentando varias cosas sin obtener resultado, estoy seguro que es problema de mi estructura MVC, autoload y el .htaccess y no logro encontrar información que me sea útil. De todas formas muchas gracias por tus comentarios